# SQL запрос по списку параметров (Spring Data)

Tags: java, postgresql, spring, spring-data

Необходимо найти в БД (Postgres) всех юзеров или операторов (role) по списку регионов (List regions)

```
@GetMapping(value = "users-ext/findUsersByRegions/{role}")
@Timed
public ResponseEntity<List<UserDto>> findUsersByRegions(@PathVariable String role, @RequestBody List<String> regions}
...
```

Проблема заключается в том, что не получается составить правильный запрос по этим параметрам, типа `List<User> findByRegionsAndAuthoritiesName(List<String> region, String role);`

```
User.java
....
@Column(name = "region")
private String region;
....
@ManyToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
@JoinTable(
    name = "jhi_user_authority",
    joinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "user_id", referencedColumnName = "id")},
    inverseJoinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "authority_name", referencedColumnName = "name")})
@Cache(usage = CacheConcurrencyStrategy.NONSTRICT_READ_WRITE)
private Set<Authority> authorities = new HashSet<>();
....
```

Найти по отдельности не проблема

```
public interface UserRepository extends JpaRepository<User, Long>, JpaSpecificationExecutor{

List<User> findByAuthoritiesName(String role); // по роли

@Query(value = "select distinct user from User user join fetch user.authorities where user.region in (:regions)")
List<User> findAllByRegions(@Param("regions") List<String> regions); // по регионам

List<User> findByRegionAndAuthoritiesName(String region, String role); // по одному региону и одной роли
....
```

Последний вариант как по мне малооптимальный, так как предполагает стучаться в БД в зависимости от количества регионов, а потом создавать отдельный список и копировать данные с каждой итерацией.

В документации необходимого ответа не нашел (может быть пропустил или не недопонял, сорри)
Кто-то сталкивался с подобным и может подсказать рабочий вариант запроса?

**UP! после ответа уважаемого Nick**

в моем случае работает

`select * from jhi_user u where exists (select * from jhi_user_authority ua where ua.user_id = u.id and ua.authority_name ='ROLE_OPERATOR') and u.region in ('r10');` подставляя значения, но увы только в консоли.

```
jhi_user_authority //промежуточная таблица с полями user_id и authority_name

jhi_authority // java класс с одним полем name (ROLE_ADMIN, ROLE_USER, ROLE_OPERATOR)

@Entity
@Table(name = "jhi_authority")
public class Authority implements Serializable {

@NotNull
@Size(min = 0, max = 50)
@Id
@Column(length = 50)
private String name;
....
```

Помогите написать для UserRepository @Query

PS Прошу ногами не пинать, проект достался в наследство, плохо владею spring data, но я стараюсь)

Comment: `user.authorities` один ко многим? `user.region` текстовая колонка?

Comment: @Nick 'user.authorities' - ManyToMany, 'user.region' - String (добавил в пост описание User.java)

Answer (score 0):

```
@Query("select u from User u where " +
        "exists (select a from Authority a where a.user = u and a.name = :role) " +
        "and u.region in :regions")
List<User> findAllByRoleAndRegions(@Param("role") String role, @Param("regions") List<String> regions);
```

Comment: Спасибо! Немного проапдейтил пост. Ваш вариант нравится и немного пошаманив, работает в консоли. Подскажите пжл, как можно добиться того же результата но через @Query? Благодарю!

Comment: @GoodWin какую ошибку выдаёт?

Comment: `PropertyReferenceException: No property inAuthorities found for type String! Traversed path: User.region.`

Comment: @GoodWin, возможно в синтаксисе ошибка